# Design QFrame and QSizeGrip

Tags: c++, qt

I created a **QFrame** and added a layout which contain **QSizeGrip** to resize that **QFrame**.

Here is **my code.pp**:

```
DragWidget::DragWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QFrame(parent)
{
    setFrameStyle(QFrame::Sunken | QFrame::StyledPanel);
    //Set flag to resize
    setWindowFlags(Qt::SubWindow);
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(this);
    layout->setContentsMargins(QMargins());
    layout->setSpacing(0);
    //Add size grip (to resize) to layout
    QSizeGrip * sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(this);
    layout->addWidget(sizeGrip, 0, 0, 1, 1, Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignRight);
}
```

I want to **design that QFrame has a background** like this:

[image]

Moreover is there any way to **customize the icon resize of QSizeGrip** (make it more clearly...).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the QSizeGrip using style sheet.
Here an example: [Customizing QSizeGrip](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qsizegrip)

Here the Qt style sheet documentation: [Qt Style Sheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/stylesheet.html)

In your case you can add this line of code:

```
sizeGrip->setStyleSheet("QSizeGrip { image: url(yourFolder/yourImage.png); }");
```

In a similar way you can customize the QFrame background, setting an image that will be repeated. See [Customizing QFrame](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qframe) and [List of properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties)

**EDIT**

Another approach is subclassing the `QSizeGrip` and reimplement the `paintEvent()` method (and maybe `sizeHint()` depending on the icon size). Here an example [Analog Clock Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html)

Comment: This work great, but if i add a button in that layout and then add the sizegrip, the icon will disappear. (If i dont use an image, default sizegrip icon show normally). In addition, do you have any ideas about the QFrame background. Many thanks to you.

Comment: For the QFrame background see my edits in the answer. For the icon, not sure, but try also to set the size of the QSizeGrip in the style sheet as shown in the linked example (Customizing QSizeGrip)

Comment: Still have the icon error. About the QFrame i think i will use QPainter to draw. If you have any further suggestion, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah i used the QPainter to draw it. To be more specific, i used QPoint and for loop. Thank you anyway.